# enqueue_script not working

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

quick question here.

I am adding custom javascript to my wordpress site, i have header-tab.js saved in the child theme's js folder, and tried to call on it with enqueue_script in my child theme's functions.php as shown here:

```
function includes_header_tab()
{
wp_enqueue_script( 'header-tab', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/header-tab.js', array( 'jquery' )); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'includes_header_tab');
?>
```

this does not seem to work, can anyone see if there is a problem in my code? or am i missing something? or it might be my javascript file that is at fault?

Comment: Is there an error you're getting on the screen or is it just that your javascript functions aren't firing correctly?

Comment: Use wp_enqueue_script( 'header-tab', dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')).'/js/header-tab.js', array( 'jquery' ));

Comment: everything on the site loads, but the javascript is just not taking effect as it is supposed to

Comment: ooh! thank you for telling me about get_bloginfo, now the js loads in the webpage... however it does not seem to take effect and i feel that i need to redo some of my js files

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a couple of data, first register and then enqueue

```
 function includes_header_tab()
    {
    wp_register_script( 'header-tab', get_template_directory_uri('/js/header-tab.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' )); 

    wp_enqueue_script( 'header-tab' );
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'includes_header_tab');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the [get_directory_template_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) manual page:

> In the event a child theme is being used, the parent theme directory URI will be returned, get_template_directory_uri() should be used for resources that are not intended to be included in/over-ridden by a child theme. Use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() to include resources that are intended to be included in/over-ridden by the Child Theme.

You simply got the parent's uri and not the child's.

Comment: thank you for telling me that, however with function changed, the js still is not taking effect, i think the problem might also be somewhere else

Comment: the JS is loaded? try viewing the source and search for a 'header-tab.js' reference

Comment: yes the Js is loaded, i see the script tag in the head of the html... so this probably means that the problem lies within my js itself?